# I can't get any css or js file in ejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Node replaces the contents of the files I call with a 404 page.

app.js

```
...

app.get(["/:username/ucp"],(req,res) => {
    res.render("ucp", 
    {
        baslik: "Karakter istatistik ekranı",
        character: req.params.username
    })
})

app.use((req, res) => {
    res.render("404")
})

...
```

404.ejs

```
<html style="padding:0">
    <head>

    </head>
    <body style="height:100%; background-color:rgb(198, 198, 198); padding:0; margin:0">
        <div style="height: 100%; display:flex; flex-direction:column; justify-content:center; align-items:center;">
            <div style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:72px; font-weight:700; color:rgb(103, 103, 103); text-align:center;">PAGE NOT FOUND</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I send a request to server like localhost:3000/adam/ucp

It show to me "ucp.ejs" but with just html codes. When I look at the js and css codes that I tried to include from the browser console, I see that their contents have been replaced with the 404.ejs file.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRaRc.png)